# npm seems to be messing up my shell script which invokes uglifyjs

Tags: npm

I have webpack use babel to transpile es6 files into es5. I want to compress these using uglifyjs. The method I used which worked till today was to have this script file be invoked with npm:

`scripts/uglifyjs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

for file in ./public/assets/js/*.js
do
    echo "uglifying `basename $file`"
    uglifyjs --verbose --compress --source-map content=${file:2}.map,url=`basename $file`.map,filename=${file:2}.map,includeSources=true --output $file $file
done
```

And in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "uglifyjs": "scripts/uglifyjs",
```

Take the first file that gets invoked, `links.js`. If I manually type the command is works:

```
$ uglifyjs --verbose --compress --source-map content=public/assets/js/links.js.map,url=links.js.map,filename=public/assets/js/links.js.map,includeSources=true --output ./public/assets/js/links.js ./public/assets/js/links.js
INFO: Using input source map: public/assets/js/links.js.map
```

When running `npm run uglifyjs` I get the following error:

```
$ npm run uglifyjs

> jbuk-frontend@0.0.1 uglifyjs /home/jonny/git/jonnybarnes.uk
> scripts/uglifyjs

uglifying links.js
fs.js:651
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'content=public/assets/js/links.js.map,url=links.js.map,filename=public/assets/js/links.js.map,includeSources=true'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:651:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1300:33)
    at done (/home/jonny/git/jonnybarnes.uk/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:516:20)
    at cb (/home/jonny/git/jonnybarnes.uk/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:324:39)
    at /home/jonny/git/jonnybarnes.uk/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:391:9
    at tryToString (fs.js:512:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:500:12)
```

I don’t know why I can run the command manually, but not via npm, it worked before. Is this a known change with npm v5?

Comment: What versions of Node & NPM are you using? If you are using NPM 5.*, do you have a package-lock.json file in your repo?

Comment: Yup, just switched from yarn back to npm, so I do have a `package-lock.json`